# Multiple monitor update

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors

I have a Bravia and a Fujitsu a series. I want to setup a dual screen but the screen resolution display setting multiple display does not give the option of extend this display, it only allows me to display desktop on either 1 or 2. I've connected them with an HDMI cable.

Any ideas on how to fix this or at least find the problem?

Its a Intel(R) HD graphics family. Video driver is dated 2011/04/15. I went to device manager, display adapter and tried to update the drive software, Windows says it's up to date. My Windows is the starter series.

As far as I know its doesn't allow this function I think that's the problem. Anyway around this?

Comment: I don't get what you mean. You want to mirror your desktop? (have the same desktop on both screens) or you want extended screen functionality, with a desktop on each? Also, I assume it is Windows 7?

Answer (score 2):

Windows Starter has severely limited functionalities.

As you can see in [Compare Windows # Feature comparison](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/products/compare?T1=tab15), **Multiple monitor support** is one of the features that have been disabled.